# HIbernate with karaf and MS-sql not working

Tags: hibernate, maven, apache-karaf

I am connecting Hibernate 5 with MSSQL 2012 . I am able to get the connection successfully with java (main method).But when I deployed in Karaf ,It Gives me error :

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:229)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.loadDriverIfPossible(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildCreator(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:217)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)[:1.8.0_51]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)[:1.8.0_51]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)[:1.8.0_51]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)[:1.8.0_51]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:226)
```

This is my hibernate.cfg file:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<ip>:<port>/<dbname></property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">testuser</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">abc</property>

    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>


  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I have install the feature in karaf as:

```
wrap:mvn:net.sourceforge.jtds/jtds/1.3.1
```

but still error is there. The repository also contain the class(`Driver.class`) but i still get this error .Can any one please help me to figure out the issue ?? what i am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Generally in OSGi using the Driver.class to load a jdbc driver does not work. 
Instead you should use [pax-jdbc-config](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/PAXJDBC/Create+DataSource+from+config) to provide a DataSource as an OSGi service and Aries JPA to make hibernate fully OSGi ready.

I have not yet used MS-SQL but pax-jdbc also supports it. So it should generally work.

For a full example see [tasklist-ds](https://github.com/cschneider/Karaf-Tutorial/tree/master/tasklist-ds).